# Activate Office365 via Powershell (or other automated process)

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell, office365

Is it possible to activate Office (for Office 365 Business Premium) using Powershell or another process that doesn't require any GUI intervention (even some form of GUI-automatic although that wouldn't be ideal).

I've written a script to install Office 365 (using chocolatey) and create new user accounts and licences using a Powershell script, however I can't figure out how to actually activate Office such that when I open Excel for the first time, it's already activated with the account that I created.

Comment: Sounds more like you want to apply the newly created account to Office, not activate. You should review the way you phrase your question.

Comment: When I open Office, I get shown an 'Activate Office' dialog. I don't see the issue with my phrasing.

Comment: You're right, I see that dialog now. I don't agree with Microsoft's phrasing.

Comment: Maybe using this VBscript. 'cscript ospp.vbs /act' from here: http://www.apeswithcomputers.com/article/use-cscript-to-activate-office-2010-2013-2016

Comment: That needs an product key, though. From my understanding, that tool isn't intended for use with office 365

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows 10 and AzureAD Join I don't believe you are prompted to activate.  I also believe this is the case if your organization is federated and utilized SSO with integrated windows authentication.  Outside of that - you have to provide credentials into with your Office365 account to validate the subscription.